# How can I calculate the marginal effects for each group level of random effects

Tags: r, lme4, ggeffects

I'm trying to figure out if I can use a multilevel model for a project, and I need to simulate some data, fit a random effects model then generate the marginal effects for each group (participant or Subject in my case). However I cannot seem to generate varying marginal effects from my model fit, despite it matching a working example (e.g., the sleepstudy).

The sleepstudy provides a good starting example to work from:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)

data("sleepstudy")
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
me <- ggpredict(m, terms = c("Days", "Subject [sample=8]"), type = "random")
plot(me)
```

[image: varying slopes from sleepstudy]

The plot shows eight different slopes from eight different Subjects

However if I simulate data which approximately matches the sleep study, my model fit doesn't generate varying slopes and I don't know why not:

```
N = 18 # Number of people
Nt = 9 # Number of trials

d <- tibble(
  Subject = factor(sprintf("%03d", 1:N)),       # create subject numbers
  subj_b0 = rnorm(n = N, mean = 250, sd = 20),  # create random intercepts
  subj_b1 = rnorm(n = N, mean = 10, sd = 6)     # create random slopes       
) %>%                                           
  mutate(Days = list(0:Nt)) %>%
  unnest(Days) %>%
  mutate(
    Y = subj_b0 + Days*subj_b1,
    Y = Y + rnorm(n = nrow(.), sd = 15)          # Add error
  )    

fit <- lmer(Y ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), data = d)
p <- ggpredict(fit, terms = c("Days", "Subject [sample=8]"), type = "random")
plot(p)
```

[image: non-varying slopes from simulated data]

I can't for the life of me figure out why `ggpredict()` is returning the same slope for each Subject.

The model summary confirms there is variation around the slope for days, and as best I can tell the other estimated parameters are similar to the sleepstudy.

```
summary(fit)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Y ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days | Subject)
   Data: d

REML criterion at convergence: 1553.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.57322 -0.57070 -0.01073  0.59463  3.02611 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 745.22   27.30        
          Days         37.95    6.16    0.12
 Residual             176.54   13.29        
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  254.517      6.693  38.030
Days           9.033      1.492   6.053
```

sleepstudy model summary for comparison:

```
summary(m)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject)
   Data: sleepstudy

REML criterion at convergence: 1743.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9536 -0.4634  0.0231  0.4634  5.1793 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 612.10   24.741       
          Days         35.07    5.922   0.07
 Residual             654.94   25.592       
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  251.405      6.825  36.838
Days          10.467      1.546   6.771
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ggpredict()` cannot handle factors (as random effects), which are "numeric", but have levels like `001`, `002` etc. This seems to be a bug, and I will see how to fix this.

The workaround would be to change the levels for `Subject`:

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(easystats)
library(lme4)

N = 18 # Number of people
Nt = 9 # Number of trials

d <- data.frame(
  Subject = factor(1:N),                        # create subject numbers
  subj_b0 = rnorm(n = N, mean = 250, sd = 20),  # create random intercepts
  subj_b1 = rnorm(n = N, mean = 10, sd = 6)     # create random slopes       
) |>
  data_modify(Days = list(0:Nt)) |>
  tidyr::unnest(Days) |>
  data_modify(
    Y = subj_b0 + Days*subj_b1,
    Y = Y + rnorm(n = N * (Nt + 1), sd = 15)          # Add error
  )

fit <- lmer(Y ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), data = d)
p <- ggpredict(fit, terms = c("Days", "Subject [sample=8]"), type = "random")
plot(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The bug has been fixed. Try `ggeffects::install_latest()`, which should update to version 1.3.2.2, and then it should work with your original data. See https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects for other installation options.